# How to check input to see if character has letter, has repeated or is more than one character long

Tags: python

So the code below given an input, check if the input is one character long, in past guesses, and see if it is a letter. Or else it should return the message to try again. However, when trying the code out I only get the else condition and have not been able to get the if condition (which should return result). Anyone know why and how I can fix this?

```
def get_guess(past_guesses):
"""
Checks if past_guesses is 1 letter, a letter or has been used before, and 
prompts user to try again

Example:
>>> get_guess(['A', 'a', 'c', 'd'])
'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven't\
already guessed. Try again'
>>> get_guess(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
'a'

"""
answer = "'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven't\
already guessed. Try again'"

while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess.isalpha() and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in past_guesses:
        past_guesses.append(guess)
        return guess
    else:
        print (answer)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If any of the answers helped solved your question, it would be beneficial if you close your question by accepting the best answer.

Comment: This works fine for me.  Try calling your `get_guess` method using `print(get_guess(['A', 'a', 'c', 'd']))` to directly see what its returning.

Answer (score 0):

Return does not print `pass_guesses`, it returns the value from your function and if you want to use it, you need to assign it to a variable.

```
a = get_guess(['A', 'a', 'c', 'd'])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. Your code is working fine. You have to print the returned result.

```
print get_guess(['A', 'a', 'c', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `get_guess()`? When you get the prompt `Guess a letter:` and you type in anything that's not one character, then your code will run whatever's after your `else` clause.

For example, if you type in `abc` after receiving your prompt, `abc` is not one character and so you'll go to your else clause and print `answer`